# How to assign data frame names as the first row?

Tags: r, list, dataframe, modeling, weather

I have several list objects, each containing 31 dataframes, which I have names 'file1980 through to 'file2010'. These were made by splitting the original (11315 rows) data frame into 31 equal sized (365 rows) data frames using the following:

```
n <- 31   
dataList <- split(MainData, factor(sort(rank(row.names(MainData))%%n)))
    names(dataList) <- paste0("file",1980:2010)
```

The individual data frames look like this:

```
   jDate   V1     V2     V3   V4     V5          V6      V7
1   001  -6.83  -5.83  -7.83 0.05 0.8217593   8.101852 100.0
2   002  -6.33  -4.83  -7.83 0.10 2.2453704   9.259259 100.0
3   003  -5.83  -4.83  -6.83 0.30 1.9444444   8.101852  94.7
4   004  -5.83  -4.83  -6.83 0.10 1.0416667   8.101852  97.5
5   005  -6.33  -4.83  -7.83 0.00 1.1226852   9.259259  98.5
6   006  -7.83  -5.83  -9.83 0.03 2.0949074  10.416667 100.0
```

They will be exported with row names removed into *.txt files for use in another piece of software. However, this software starts by reading the first row (which is the column names incsv or txt formats), as the file name, but for the software to run the first row needs to be the file name, so 'file1980' and so on.

I'm hoping to split the list into 31 equally sized files that look like this (with sequential file names, file1980 to file 2010, in the top row):

```
    file1980
1   001  -6.83  -5.83  -7.83 0.05 0.8217593   8.101852 100.0
2   002  -6.33  -4.83  -7.83 0.10 2.2453704   9.259259 100.0
3   003  -5.83  -4.83  -6.83 0.30 1.9444444   8.101852  94.7
4   004  -5.83  -4.83  -6.83 0.10 1.0416667   8.101852  97.5
5   005  -6.33  -4.83  -7.83 0.00 1.1226852   9.259259  98.5
6   006  -7.83  -5.83  -9.83 0.03 2.0949074  10.416667 100.0
7   007  -5.33  -4.83  -5.83 0.00 1.4930556   8.101852  97.6
8   008  -7.33  -5.83  -8.83 0.00 0.9027778   9.259259 100.0
9   009  -7.33  -6.83  -7.83 0.03 0.8217593   8.101852  90.2
```

I have now seen two methods which add a new row1 with the file name, but the results here both failed to replace/remove the column names, or replaced them with NA. ON an individual file it is easy to just use names(main file) <- NULL, but this only solves half the problem.

The resulting files all need to be sent along a preset filepath.

Comment: Could you maybe post an example of your expected output?

Comment: I've added an example to illustrate

Comment: I think `tibble::add_row()` is what you need here.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe it's better not to edit the data frame to do this sort of thing, better first print the required string first to the file, then append the data.

`write.table()` is quite flexible luckily :

```
# data prep, taking 2 chunks of iris
MainData <- head(iris, 10)
# optional if you want columns with equal width in the csv :
MainData[] <- lapply(MainData, format)
n <- 2   
dataList <- split(
  MainData, 
  factor(sort(rank(row.names(MainData_formatted))%%n))
)
names(dataList) <- paste0("file",seq(n))
dataList

# print to file
for (file in names(dataList)) {
  # define the path, here in the working directory
  path <- paste0(file, ".csv")
  # print(path) # uncomment to see the path
  # print string to file
  writeLines(file, path)
  # append the data, without headers, quotes or row names
  write.table(
    dataList[[file]], path, 
    col.names = FALSE, row.names = FALSE, quote = FALSE, append = TRUE
  )
}

# in file1.csv :

# file1
# 5.1 3.5 1.4 0.2 setosa
# 4.9 3.0 1.4 0.2 setosa
# 4.7 3.2 1.3 0.2 setosa
# 4.6 3.1 1.5 0.2 setosa
# 5.0 3.6 1.4 0.2 setosa

# cleanup
file.remove(c("file1.csv", "file2.csv"))
```

`write.table()` uses `" "` as a separator, you might use `sep = "\t"` if you want it tab delimited

Comment: Yes, I agree that this is the cleaner and more general way.

Comment: When I run using the Iris dataset there is no difference from the original dataset except that it is split into to smaller datasets, but while they have names, those names don't occur on line one as required.

Comment: They do occur on line 1 of the file. A file name is not a "Sepal.Length", so I don't put it under "Sepal.Length" in a data structure, instead we write separately the file and data to the file. I feel like I'm just repeating my first sentence and my comments though. Is there a part that is unclear ?

Comment: I'm unclear on how to see the new data frames except in the console (I would like to save them to folder along a file path). Additionally, when I enter 'dataList' in the console the output shows the two new iris data frames with 'file1' titles, but also with the column names where they originally were.

Comment: I have found that I can get the data frames to csv by changing 'file <-' to my filepath, but is only sends one file.

Comment: `path <- paste0(file, ".csv")` defines the path for each file, as it is it will print the files into your working directory which you can see with `getwd()`. you might modify this path to your taste

Comment: I added a comment to print the paths, you can always use print() when you're not sure what something returns.

Comment: After a certain amount of refitting my working directory this code works as hoped. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

I do not really get what you want, maybe this helps.

```
dataList <- list(iris, iris, iris) 
names(dataList) <- paste0("file",1980:1982)
  
purrr::imap(dataList, ~.x |> 
              mutate(Sepal.Length = Sepal.Length |> as.character()) |> 
              tibble::add_row(.before = 1, Sepal.Length = .y))
```

Output:

```
$file1980
    Sepal.Length Sepal.Width Petal.Length Petal.Width    Species
1       file1980          NA           NA          NA       <NA>
2            5.1         3.5          1.4         0.2     setosa
```

Comment: The output I get in the console matches, but for some reason isn't incorporated into the dataframes as separate objects, and doesn't appear in the saved files.

Comment: There are two issues here. There is a "unexpected token '>'", and there is an error message: "Error in `mutate()`:
! Can't transform a data frame with duplicate names."

Comment: I should also add that having the file name in the row below the column names isn't what is needed. The file name shoyud replace the column names.

Comment: then the answer from moodymudskipper is the way to go Bob.

Comment: This answer has actually gotten me closest to where I want to be, all of the data frames in my list now look like this. Now I need to work out how to do something similar to remove the column names and NA's.

Comment: You can use ‘replace_na(‘’)’ to remove the NAs and unname to get rid of column names

Answer (score 0):

You can use `tibble::add_row(.before = 1)` to append a row at the top. For this to work, you need to convert the first column to `character` so you can add the table name since each `data.frame` column must be of a single `type`.

```r
library(tidyverse)

l <- list(a = data.frame(matrix(1:4, 2)),
          b = data.frame(matrix(1:4, 2)))

l <- l %>% 
  map2(.x = ., 
       .y = names(.), 
       ~.x %>% 
         mutate(across(1, as.character)) %>% 
         add_row(X1 = .y, .before = 1))

l
#> $a
#>   X1 X2
#> 1  a NA
#> 2  1  3
#> 3  2  4
#> 
#> $b
#>   X1 X2
#> 1  b NA
#> 2  1  3
#> 3  2  4
```

<sup>Created on 2022-11-22 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

Comment: Same issue as Julians answer, it looks good in the console but doesn't get saved into the  list in the global environment, which should now say 366 rows.

Comment: You just need to assign it back to `l`. In the example we're just having it print directly to show you what it looks like.

Comment: It works if I go back to the original (before I split it into a list) data frame. However on the real data it doesn't work, I get the following error: "Error in `mutate()`:
! Can't transform a data frame with duplicate names." So I'm guessing the code relies on the column names to know where to put the new first row? Also still need to drop the NA's

Comment: Yes, this requires knowing the first column name. In this example it's `X1` but will be specific to your data. If it differs between the tables in the list then this approach won't work directly for you.